# PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf problem adding a host?

Tags: configuration, postgresql

I'm having a problem with configuring my postgresql server. 
I've installed PostgreSQL 9.0.2 on slackware 13.1x64 and it runs fine but I can't add a IP that could connect to PostgreSQL remotely.

The logs show me this:

```
LOG:  invalid IP mask "trust": Name or service not known
CONTEXT:  line 83 of configuration file "/usr/local/pgsql-9.0.2/data/pg_hba.conf"
FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

And on that line I have:

```
host    all         all         **.**.***.*         trust
```

The ** is my real IP address. But PostgreSQL tells me I need to set ip mask ?
What's that I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance,
Me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to specify an IP address of the form: 192.168.0.1/24 where "/24" is an alternative representation of your Subnet-Mask.

For a local area network you often see 255.255.255.0 as a Subnet-Mask. Each part of that Mask can be translated to an 8-Bit representation (255 = 11111111). So for 3 x 255 you've got 3x 8-Bit which leads to a total of 24-Bits and there you go. Of course, you'll find more detailed explanations on the internet.

Just use http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ or ask your provider for your Subnet-Mask.

Comment: I know that. But I'm using a real IP - internet IP address not a local... :)

Comment: pg_hba.conf wants an IP mask, not an IP address. Try 127.0.0.1/32 or whatever your IP address is.

Comment: @AlexHolst Thanks, I wonder why that wouldn't accept both form (i.e., CIDR and plain IP).